# Firebase Cloud Messaging Reports - not displaying sent count in Reports

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We have set "analytics_label" in the message as stated in the documentation and the message is getting delivered as well. But we do not see any entry in the report. Please check our message string and let us know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

### REST API being called

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

### Message being sent

{"topic":"81xxxxx42","android":{"priority":"high"},"priority":"high","fcm_options":{"analytics_label":"nwy81xxxxx42"},"data":{"MID":-1,"frm":"99xxxxx32","MTP":9,"msg":""}}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what library you're using or if you're just POSTing directly to the REST API, but looking at code that I know works I think you just need to make fcm_options and analytics_label camel case.

```
{
    "topic": "81xxxxx42",
    "android": {
        "priority": "high"
    },
    "priority": "high",
    "fcmOptions": {
        "analyticsLabel": "nwy81xxxxx42"
    },
    "data": {
        "MID": -1,
        "frm": "99xxxxx32",
        "MTP": 9,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```